# Datatables: Combining two columns to create one select for search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a simple datatable which looks like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Anchorage</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Toronto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- etc -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to create a select option to filter the results of all the table, but would like it to feature data from both columns. For example:

```
<select>
 <option>Anchorage</option>
 <option>Calgary</option>
 <option>Vancouver</option>
 <option>Toronto</option>
</select>
```

And at the moment I get

```
<select>
 <option>Anchorage</option>
 <option>Calgary</option>
</select>
```

I have tried using columnDefs but not sure how to get it to combine the two column data in to one select without affecting the display of the two columns.

This is the jQuery I am using

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

    initComplete: function () {

      this.api().columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
          .on( 'change', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
              .draw();
          } );

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
          select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
        } );
      } );
    }

} );


table.on('draw', function () {
    table.columns().indexes().each( function ( idx ) {
      var select = $(table.column( idx ).footer()).find('select');

      if ( select.val() === '' ) {
        select
          .empty()
          .append('<option value=""/>');

        table.column(idx, {search:'applied'}).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
          select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
        } );
      }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Do you want to add `option` contain `td`s texts that is uniq?

Comment: I can do it without datatables and with regex, I haven't looked at datatables for a long time but if I remember rightly their docs are pretty good. Look for search and/or filter functions here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: I just want to be able to create one select from the two columns instead of showing two (which is what it does now).
ie: Combine both value sets one to one select.

Comment: @IanFraser Can you show `select` result that you want.

Comment: Yes, I can show the result I want, I just am not generating all the options i need in the select.

Comment: @IanFraser Is first `select` you show what you want?

Comment: @Mohammad yes, the select with 4 options is what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @IanFraser Is it your purpose?

Comment: Sorry not quite working, I'll put up some additional jquery which is used when calling in the datatable. Nice idea though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("tbody td").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if ($("select > option:contains('" + text + "')").length == 0)
        $("select").append("<option>" + text + "</option>");
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Anchorage</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Toronto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vancouver</td>
        <td>Calgary</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by adding the following.

In the table I added 2 x classes to the tfoot:

```
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th class="sel1">From</th>
        <th class="sel2">To</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

And then added the following jQuery at the bottom:

```
    $("tbody td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
    if ($(".sel1 select > option:contains('" + text + "')").length == 0)
        $(".sel1 select").append("<option>" + text + "</option>");
});


$('.sel1 select').unbind().on('change', function() {
    var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchTerm);
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
       //search only in column 1 and 2
       if (~data[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
       if (~data[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
       return false;
   })
   table.draw(); 
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
})
```

The above jQuery is class driven to target the correct select and add the values. The bottom function is then a custom function for searching across the two columns. Taken from: [How can I search multiple columns in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799176/how-can-i-search-multiple-columns-in-datatables)