# jQuery datatable with custom search bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to search in the columns 'Part Number' and 'Internal Reference' with one searchbar and with another searchbar in the column named 'Description':

[image]

By the moment I'm trying with this in the html:

```
...
<th class="code">Part Number</th>
<th class="keyword">Description</th>
<th class="code">Internal Reference</th>
...
```

And this in the .js:

```
$('#keyword-search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    oTable.columns('.keyword').search('^' + val, true, false).draw();
});

$('#code-search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    oTable.columns('.code').search('^' + val, true, false).draw();
});
```

I want to be able to search in the 'Part Number' or in the 'Reference' column but not in both at the same time, just to show the columns where the expression exists in the first or in the second column.

I need this to be solved, I tried different ways and I don't find the solution.

**EDIT 1:** I want a final result like this:

[image]

But that search is not working, there is no final filtered result, there is a collision between the two columns because it's searching 'NUM1' in the column 'Part Number' and in the column 'Internal Reference' at the same time. I mean that the code it's doing an *AND* search instead of an *OR* search, that is what I want.

Comment: Can you provide a working example with actual data and the two search bars? It will be much easier to assist this way.

Comment: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33802340/7224597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
    $('#keyword-search').keyup(function() {
        var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        //Assuming part number and internal reference are 1st and 3rd columns
        if((~data[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText)) || (~data[2].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText))) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Check [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33802340/7224597)

Comment: Perfect this is what I wanted, now the only problem is that it should show the rows where the code _startsWith_ the content of the bar, but I think that's a minor problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the `caret(^)` should do the trick for you. Happy to help.

Comment: I finally used `data[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) === 0` instead of `~data[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(val)`. Just in case someone needs it.