# DataTables - Search in multiple columns with a single drop down

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I'm working with DataTables and i'm trying to search a result in a table with a dropdown. But rather than searching one column, I need to search in two specific columns.

The below syntax works with a single column but how do i do it with multiple columns?

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
    $("#filter").on('change', function() {
        table.column([4]).search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
```

I tried doing this but when i use this code it only searches the result in the first column, E.g. 4th Column. and ignores the rest.

```
        table.column([4,5]).search($(this).val()).draw();
```

What is the proper method for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search multiple columns in DataTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799176/how-can-i-search-multiple-columns-in-datatables)

Comment: Not a duplicate because Range Search performs search on single column within a given range of different inputs.

Comment: @Terry it's not the same sorry. I need to do the search in two specific columns.

Comment: For your scenarios, here is another extension of datatable called [fnMultiFilter](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnMultiFilter) which do search on multi columns.

Comment: @mmushtaq isn't there a way to do it like in my code?

Comment: @KasunWijesekara you will have to create a temporary column that contains a concatenation of the two other columns and search in it, make sure it's hidden :)

Comment: May be there is but till now i couldn't find it. [**Here is jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/sknnda1o/) for fnMultiFilter.

Comment: @KasunWijesekara `table.column(4).search(this.value).column(5).search(this.value).draw();` . try this one.

Comment: @mmushtaq nope no luck.

Comment: [This is updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/eq42w11w/). I removed fnMultiFilter and just used above code. It is working.

Comment: @mmushtaq here's the view of my table. https://gyazo.com/be4a18da8b668117305999c58d5963f7 , with your code it only shows "Pending" keyword. Approved and Rejected doesn't show up with any results.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/v65db2ez/ . See this

Comment: You are filtering both columns, so the filter input text much match the data in both columns. Suppose if your `reject` and `approved` columns both contains `Pending` status then your filter result will have matching rows in both columns.

Comment: Yep your method works. I just need to make adjustments to my datatable. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets summarize all things here. It will help other people as well.

You can achieve this as follow:

```
table.column(4).search(this.value).column(5).search(this.val‌​ue).draw();
```

It will perform search on 4 column (4 is index of column), after that it will filter data from 5 column against provided filter value and at the end it will draw the table.

One thing to keep in mind is that Filter is applied on both columns, so both columns must contains matching data.

<kbd>[**Here is its filddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/v65db2ez/)</kbd>

---

This can be achieved by using [**fnMultiFilter**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnMultiFilter) as it documentation explains:

*This plug-in adds to DataTables the ability to set multiple column filtering terms in a single call (particularly useful if using server-side processing). Used in combination with the column sName parameter, simply pass in an object with the key/value pair being the column you wish to search on, and the value you wish to search for.*

Answer (score 5):

Use [columns()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns()) in place of column():

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
$("#filter").on('change', function() {
    table.columns([4,5]).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc, you should be using [`.columns()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns()) (note the plural)

Answer (score 1):

For an OR search among multiple columns, disable columns for the search using

> [columns.searchableSince: Enable or disable search on the data in a certain column.](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable)

Alternatively, you can also use an HTML attribute to remove the column from the search

```
<th data-searchable=false>
```