# jQuery Datatables search by multiple columns using OR operator

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to filter / search a jQuery Datatable. In order to achieve the proper result I need only those rows which meet the following condition:

```
(COLUMN 4 == '1')  OR (COLUMN 5 == '1')
```

Practically I have 20 columns, but my search is actually a row filtering which should filter by 2 columns using OR. I cannot search independently each column.

Answer (score 2):

You can search whit a Regex like this:

```
var regExSearch = '(AFGHANISTAN|COLOMBIA)';
table.columns([0,1]).search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically turn `searchable` off for all columns but those you want to search on :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 columnDefs: [
    { targets: [4,5], searchable: true },    
    { targets: '_all', searchable: false }
  ]
})
```

Now you have a distinct columns `or` search. Notice the order, it is important that you declare those columns you want to have `searchable` first. If you want a more sophisticated `or` search, you can create a [**custom  filter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799176/how-can-i-search-multiple-columns-in-datatables).